# I have problem OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 6651904, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 9406464)

Tags: python, tensorflow, testing, keras, model

I have this Error when run code in down:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProjects\AIToDetectGloves\AIToDetectGloves.py", line 30, in <module>
    tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet'),
  File "C:\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\keras\applications\mobilenet_v2.py", line 481, in MobileNetV2
    model.load_weights(weights_path)
  File "C:\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 567, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)
  File "C:\Python3.11\Lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 231, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 6651904, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 9406464)
```

I have this code and run it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#have to folder train and test in train to folder cat and dog
train_data_dir = "C:\PythonProjects\AIToDetectGloves\Dataset\train"
test_data_dir = "C:\PythonProjects\AIToDetectGloves\Dataset\test"

# Define image data generators for data preprocessing
image_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 32

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir,
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

# Define the model architecture
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet'),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
epochs = 10
model.fit(train_generator,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=test_generator)

# Save the trained model
model.save("dog_classifier_model.h5")
```

I have folder train in train I have folder with cat and folder with dog and in the train the same.

In folder cat I have image with cats and in folder dags i have image with dogs.

142 with cats and 72 with dog.
Why I see this error?

Comment: Hi @Pythoner, There could be reason that h5py module has not installed. Please try again installing h5py module using - `pip install h5py` to support downloading weights of MobileNetV2 pretrained model to use and rerun the code. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.